# C# Sockets(Connection is not established)

Tags: c#, sockets

Here is my client

```
static Socket sck;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
        try
        {
            sck.Connect(localEndpoint);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Unable to connect local endpoint! \r\n ");
            Main(args);
        }
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        sck.Send(data);
        Console.Write("Data sent ! \r\n");
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.Read();
        sck.Close();
    }
```

Here is my Server.

```
 static byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
    static Socket sck;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,  ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
        sck.Listen(100);
        Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
        Buffer = new byte[accepted.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int byteReades = accepted.Receive(Buffer);
        byte[] formatted = new byte[byteReades];
        for (int i = 0; i < byteReades; i++)
        {
            formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
        }
        string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
        Console.Write(strData + "\r\n");
        sck.Close();
        accepted.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

When I am trying to run the client in order to send data to the server, I am facing with the SocketException "Connection is not established on 127.0.0.1 :1234" . error code is 10061.
Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: I copied the code you gave in 2 new console applications. One for client, one for server. They both work 100% fine. 

The issue most likely is something on your end. Perhaps a firewall settings. The code however works fine.

Comment: On what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: I think your firewall is blocking the port 1234... the error 10061 is a "connection refused" error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you are right the problem with firewall settings, but what I need to change in that setting.

Comment: on this line. sck.Connect(localEndpoint);

Comment: TCP.. accept all in from por 1234.
TCP.. accept all out from por 1234.
And try to put your intranet IP and not 127.0.0.1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most definitely a firewall issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

ctrl+f and search 100061. This is a pretty good habit to be in when working with Socket Exceptions because you can get some meaning out of the error code number(usually, sometimes this isn't very helpful). this error code falls under the "No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it" group. More details on the link.

It is also possible that The Socket was not quickly released or if your lucky was already in use by something else. I would check firewall settings first since this is a pretty easy thing to do.

Comment: What I need to change in firewall settings to solve this bug, just I am beginner in this technologies

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify a firewall exception. You can use the command-line to do this as specified in [this handy KB article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Example:

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Socket Test" dir=in action=allow remoteip=127.0.0.1 protocol=TCP localport=1234`

Then later remove it:

`netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Socket Test"`

Comment: Sir, the same exception.

Comment: Then you pretty much have no choice but to configure a firewall exception. I would suggest however not to explicitly set ANY/ANY on 127.0.0.1 as it could be misused.

Comment: I added an example of how to do it with netsh

Answer (score 0):

As M. Avery noted, this definitely sounds like a firewall / port issue. I've tested your code and it works fine.

If you're using Windows Firewall on Windows 7, check out this link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

Comment: In my view that is not a firewall issue, because I disabled Firewall from my machine and without firewall I am facing with the same exception.It does not mean that the problem not in a firewall settings??